# is there any solution to call this service for dropdown list in angular 10?

Tags: angular, typescript

```js
getDealersList(data){
  //return this.http.get<Dealers>(`${environment.apiUrl+'dealership/get'}`,data,this.httpOption());
  return this.http.post(this.apiUrl+ 'dealerships/get',data,this.httpOption());
}
```

How to call this service in typescript file to make a dropdown list please help me out with this. I need a API call or service call for this.

Comment: What does this request gives you ?

Answer (score 0):

As what I understand from your mentioned description, you want to call Restful API's but you are unable to do! right?

Let me guide you step by step

**Step 01: create Api Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class ApiService{

  apiUrl: string = "YOUR API BASE URL";

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
  }

  httpOption(){
    return { 
      // return your httpOptions 
    };
  }

  getDealersList(data): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl+ 'dealerships/get',data,this.httpOption());
  }
}
```

**Step 02: Consume ApiService within your component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dealers',
  templateUrl: './dealers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dealers.component.css']
})
export class DealersComponent implements OnInit {
  
  data: any;  

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService){ 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = {} // assign data which you want to pass 
    this.fetchDealersList();
  }

  async fetchDealersList() {
    try{
      let response = await this.apiService.getDealersList(this.data).toPromise();
      console.log(response);
    } catch(e) {
      console.error(e)
    }   
  }
}
```

**Note:** This is not a proper solution, you may get help from this to populate dropdown list